# How to add custom icon theme to Plank dock?

Tags: gnome, icons, .desktop, plank

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Plank
GenericName=Dock
Categories=Utility;
Type=Application
Exec=plank
Icon=/usr/share/icons/Numix-Circle/applications.svg
Terminal=false
NoDisplay=false
```

I want my Plank to have a custom icon theme(Numix-Circle) and have the rest of the system run Papirus as the icon theme. The above code is what I put in the .desktop file of Plank. I also restarted Gnome(Alt+F2 and r). However, the changes are not reflected and it still has the Parirus icons. Where am I wrong?